# $\ker f^k=\mathrm{Span}(e_{n-k+1}, e_{n-k+1}, \dots ,e_{n})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb R^n$ be a linear operator with $ f(e_i)=e_{i+1}$ for $1\leq i \leq n - 1$ and $f(e_{n})=0$. How do I prove that $\ker f^k=\mathrm{Span}(e_{n-k+1}, e_{n-k+1}, \dots ,e_{n})$ for $k \in \mathbb N$, $1\leq k \leq n$.

I tried to prove by induction on $k \in \mathbb N$, because I know that $\ker f=\mathrm{Span}(e_{n})$ and $\ker f^2=\mathrm{Span}(e_{n-1},\ e_{n})$ and so on.

But I don't know how to formalize this and how can I prove the induction step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can describe easily how $f^k$ operates: it sends $e_i$ to $e_{i+k}$ whenever $i+k\leq n$, and to zero otherwise. Then it sends general vectors $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(0,\ldots,0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k})$. In order for that to be zero, it is necessary and sufficient that $0=x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{n-k}$; this defines $\ker(f^k)$. Now it remains to prove that the vectors $e_{n-k+1},\ldots,e_n$, each of which clearly satisfies these equations and so lies in $\ker(f^k)$, span all of that kernel; this is an easy exercise (compare dimensions for instance).

Comment: What do you mean by comparing dimensions?

Comment: When (finite dimensional) subspaces $U,W$ are known to satisfy $U\subseteq W$, then it suffices to establish $\dim(U)=\dim(W)$ in order to prove $U=W$. (This is because all _proper_ subspaces $U'\subset W$ have $\dim(U')<\dim(W)$.) This applies here with $W=\ker(f^k)$ and $U=\operatorname{span}(e_{n-k+1},\ldots,e_n)$. You do need to compute $\dim(U)$ and $\dim(W)$ and observe that they are equal.

Comment: I showed that $Span(e_{n-k+1}, e_{n-k+2},\dots,e_{n})\subseteq \ker T^k$. but whats a good way to compute $\dim (U)$ and $\dim (W)$? I think that the dimension of both of them is $k$, is that right?

Comment: Since the set of spanning vectors contains $k$ vectors, showing that the space spanned has dimension $k$ is precisely showing that those vectors are linearly independent; that should not be too hard to do. For the dimension of $\ker(f^k)$, you can use rank-nullity; can you show that the rank of $f^k$ is $n-k$? (Actually "rank at least $n-k$" is what matters: that implies $\dim\ker(f^k)$ is at most $k$, and given the linear independence we already know that it is at least$~k$.)